# Listar execução ordenadamente com PHP

Tags: php

eu estou trabalhando num código de playlist de música com PHP, então eu estou colocando o comando para tocar a música pela variável $filename:

```
echo "<br><embed src=\"$folder/$filename\" widht=1 height=50><br>";
```

Mas quando eu executo esse comando, ele toca todas as músicas da pasta e não uma por uma (ordenadamente) como eu gostaria. Como eu posso fazer isso? Seguem os códigos completos:

index.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
echo '<form action="list.php">';
echo "<h4>Write your songs folder</h4><br>";
echo "<h5>(DON'T WRITE A BAR IN THE END OR WRITE ANY SPECIAL CHARACTER)</h5>";
echo '<input type="text" name="folder">';
echo '<input type="submit">';
echo "</form>";
```

list.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

$folder = $_GET["folder"];
$files  = "{$folder}/".$_GET['/*.*'];

if(isset($_GET['folder']) && file_exists("{$folder}/".$_GET['/*.*'])){

$fold = opendir($folder);

    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($fold))) { 

        if (substr($filename,-4) == ".mp3") { 
        echo "<br><embed src=\"$folder/$filename\" widht=1 height=50><br>";

}

}

}
```

Comment: Mas você quer que inicie tocando?

Comment: Em vez de imprimir diretamente o que o "readdir" retorna, você deve por e conteúdo em um Array e ordenar o mesmo da forma que achar melhor. Depois disso, basta imprimir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, seu problema mais tem a ver com JavaScript do que com PHP. Você quer que as músicas sejam tocadas uma depois da outra, certo?

Então, por favor, em vez de usar a tag `embed`, use a tag [`audio`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp):

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="pasta/arquivo.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

assim, no PHP:

```
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($fold))) { 
    if (substr($filename,-4) == ".mp3") { 
        echo "<audio controls><source src=\"$folder/$filename\" type=\"audio/mp3\"></audio><br>";
    }
}
```

Para que cada música toque após o fim de sua antecessora, use javascript:

```
<script>
    function play_next(event) {
        var next = event.target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling
        if (next)// se existir uma próxima música
           next.play();// a toca
    }
    var musicas = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'); // seleciona todas as musicas
    var len = musicas.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        musicas[i].onended=play_next; // quando essa música acabar, chama play_next
    musicas[0].play(); // toca a primeira
</script>
```

Comment: @Alexandre-Layonel Muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a documentação da função readdir:

> Retorna o nome de arquivo do próximo arquivo do diretório. Os nomes de
>   arquivos são retornados na ordem informada pelo sistema de arquivos.
>   (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php

Você vai obter uma lista ordenada de acordo com o sistema operacional. Caso você queira uma ordem diferente, recomendo que itere os arquivos do diretório e adicione em um Array. Dessa forma:

```
$files = [];
if(isset($_GET['folder']) && file_exists("{$folder}/".$_GET['/*.*'])){
$fold = opendir($folder);
      while (false !== ($filename = readdir($fold))) { 

        if (substr($filename,-4) == ".mp3") { 
        $files[] = $filename;

      }
   }
}
```

Então você pode utilizar a função sort do PHP caso deseje ordem alfabética.

```
$files = sort($files,SORT_STRING);
```

E então você imprime as tags:

```
foreach($files as $file) {

      echo "<br><embed src=\"$folder/$file\" widht=1 height=50><br>";
}
```

Caso não seja ordem alfabetica(você não definiu), você deverá ordenar o Array  manualmente conforme critério desejado.

Comment: Muito obrigado :D